# 'str' object has no attribute 'session'

Tags: python, django, attributes, e-commerce

Im going through the "beginning Django ecommerce" book, and I am stuck on trying to show the "go to cart" link on all the pages.

I get this `error: 'str' object has no attribute 'session'` and the line

`"{% cart_box request%}"` in the HTML is highlighted with this error.

this is the HTML

```
{% load catalog_tags %}

<div class="cart_box">

    {% cart_box request %}

</div>

{% if hour == 7 or hour == 9 or hour == 12 %}   

Order time = {{hour}}
```

this is the view.

```
def menu_hour(request,hour):

    #set the test cookie
    request.session.set_test_cookie()

    hour = int(hour)
    food = Food.objects.all()
    output = ', '.join([f.name for f in food])

    steak = Food.objects.get(name="Steak and Egg Burrito")
    steak.price = 15
    steak.save()

    queso = Food.objects.get(name="Queso Burrito")
    queso.time = hour

    food_dict = {"steak": steak, "queso": queso, "hour":hour}
    return render_to_response('menu_hour.html', food_dict, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

this is the catalog tag

```
from django import template 
from cart import cart

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag("tags/cart_box.html") 
def cart_box(request):
    cart_item_count = cart.cart_distinct_item_count(request) 
    return {'cart_item_count': cart_item_count }
```

this is the catalog tag HTML

```
{% with cart_item_count as cart_count %} 
    <a href="{% url show_cart %}">
        Shopping Cart
        <br />
        {{ cart_count }} Item{{ cart_count|pluralize }}
    </a>
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: The only object on which you call 'session' is request, in the first line of def menu_hour. This indicates that request is a string. Where are you calling the function?

Comment: but i'm passing "request" when i call render_to_response, which should send the request to my html page. no?

Comment: From where you're calling the menu_hour view? Are you calling manually or it's being called from the urls.py?

Comment: @anc1revv, he means calling menu_hour() as part of another view.  Perhaps your urls.py defines the url as being handled by toplevelView(), and toplevelView() is calling menu_hour() with the first argument wrong.

Comment: no other view calls this one.  I am calling it manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because i wasn't passing "request" in my dictionary to the template.